# Entity Framework Designers

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Are there any EF designers out there that actually work?  I would like to find an EF designer that isn't the default VS 2008 one.   I have a relation between two entities that is absurdly wrong.  No, actually I have a related field, it can't highlight the relationship for me because it doesn't exist.  I could just exclude the field from scaffolding, but that is not the right approach.

Right now I'm just deleting and rebuilding my whole damn model, because it's a lot quicker and requires a lot less freaking Xanax!

Comment: Is this a real question or just a rant ?

Comment: Did you miss the first sentence @Tomas, the one ending with a question mark?

Comment: If you don't like the current one, you're stuck until VS 2010 comes out.

Comment: @Dave, or until I bite the bullet and download the beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I don't believe there are any alternative EF designers... You could try a different data access technology like LinqToSql or NHibernate though.